# How to post arabic text using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, http, post, curl, arabic

How to post Arabic text using cURL in PHP?

```
$postData = array(
    'msg' => 'مرحبا'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Comment: What's not working with your current code?

Comment: Is your PHP page encoding UTF-8? Have you used meta tags in your HTML to indicate the file is UTF-8?

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

The CURL POST in the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind.

SO i think you need to set the charset.

Can you try adding this with other options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

encode the posted data with `urlencode`...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the headers and set options as follows:

```
$header = array("Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
```

Then you can post your data.

And finally, don't forget to commit:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<commit />");
```

(This is taken from a working implementation)

Answer (score 0):

try this, when using get method.

```
<?php
//step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.google.com/search?q=curl");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
//step4
curl_close($cSession);
//step5
echo $result;
?>
```